# Input changing row count matrices in an MLP

Tags: keras, numpy, mlp

I want to input a numpy 2d array into MLP but I have an array of 50395 rows that contains many 2d array of shape `(x, 129)`. `x` because some matrices have different row numbers. Here is an example :

```
train['spec'].shape
>>(50395,)
train['spec'][0].shape
>>(41, 129)
train['spec'][5].shape
>>(71, 129)
```

Here an snippet of my code :

```
X_train = train['spec'].values;     X_valid = valid['spec'].values
y_train = train['label'].values;    y_valid = valid['label'].values
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(50395, ), activation='relu'));
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), epochs=500, batch_size=1);
```

I get this error on last line (`model.fit`) :
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_54_input to have shape (50395,) but got array with shape (1,)`

How to fix this problem so that the network can take as input all `50395` matrices of shape `(x, 129)`?

Comment: reshape all your data in vector format, each stack row after row

Comment: It will don't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I made the matrices (x, 129) to have the same shape by padding in with the rows filled with zeros.

Second, I transformed my large matrices into dimension 3 by the following process:

```
train = list(train_df['spec'])
np.array(train).shape
>>> (50395, 71, 129)


X_train = list(train['spec']);     X_valid = list(valid['spec'])
y_train = train['label'].values;    y_valid = valid['label'].values
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(50395, 71, 129), activation='relu'));
model.fit(np.array(X_train), y_train, validation_data=(np.array(X_valid), y_valid), epochs=500, batch_size=1);
```